# How can I connect a bath wall spout intended for copper to a brass water supply outlet?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, walls, interior, bathroom-fixtures

I'm in the process of remodeling a bathroom and am getting ready to tile the walls surround the tub/shower.  I'm stumped on how to connect the bath spout.

The spout looks like this:

[image: bath spout]

As you can see, it's all one piece and from what I can dig up online, it's intended to slip over 1/2" copper pipe.

The problem? I don't have a copper pipe extending out.

Here's what my shower valve side looks like:

[image: shower wall]

About 4-5 inches inside, is a screw-on outlet (sorry - that likely isn't the right terminology).  Here's a picture:

[image]

So my question comes down to this:  How can I connect that spout to that outlet with minimal intrusion to the wall (so I don't have to reapply the whole hardie board slab)?  Is there some sort of adapter for connecting copper to brass?

Comment: I think you should be able to get a piece of copper pipe with the fitting and have it sticking out the wall, of course cut to length. If you look from the bottom of the spout, there should be an Allen-head set screw there which you will use to tighten the fixture onto the pipe. Look where the hole is at in the bottom and you should be able to see it. I'm not sure, so leaving as a comment.

Comment: @Paulster2 Thanks for the prompt feedback. Can you elaborate? I agree that I need a piece of copper pipe with some sort of adapter fitting but what is it called? Do I need to make that or do they come preassembled?

Comment: You I would have thought you could find something preassembled, but coming up with nothing. So, you'd need a fitting [like this](http://www.lowes.com/pd_21840-137-CL604_4294822005__?productId=3505126&Ns=p_product_qty_sales_dollar|1&pl=1&currentURL=%3FNs%3Dp_product_qty_sales_dollar%7C1&facetInfo=) and some 1/2" copper to go into it. It would have to be soldered together, though. Make sure you put some teflon tape on the threads. Looking at yours though, it looks to be something of a fine thread. The fittings you get are going to be a pipe thread which is rather coarse. This is still a comment.

Comment: I'd wait for better instructions, because I just don't know for sure what you'd be using.

Comment: For the next person, here is a similar install to compare to https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/126302/shower-arm-thread-sticking-out-of-wall-is-too-long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stock fitting - Male Pipe Thread to sweat (ie, soldered copper) Solder to a section of pipe, screw in, enjoy.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A pipe stub should have been installed before that wall was closed. Remove the piece of backer board and re-do it right.

There's no tile installed, so it's not much work to remove and reinstall un-tiled backer board.  Compared to dealing with an in-wall leak from a poorly installed threaded copper connection those 20 minutes "extra" work are a bargain..

Remove the screws, take down the board.  Take the fitting shown in the previous post, sweat it on 4-6" piece of copper type L pipe.  Teflon tape the fitting's threads. Use an adjustable flat jaw wrench to tighten the fitting.  Replace the backer board.

btw Fasteners are the weak link in a tile job. If moisture gets into the plumbed wall, through leaks of by condensation, regular drywall screws will eventually rust and weaken. If stainless trumpet head (deck) screws are used,they won't corrode no matter what you cover the wall with.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Good answer; keep 'em coming!